# How to provide a fallback CSS until the actual CSS is loaded?

Tags: html, css

The problem that I am facing is specific to Google Search Console.

What's happening is that for whatever reason, their Mobile Usability test suite fails to load CSS about half the time. Resulting in the following errors in the report:

[image]

Here is the subject page: https://ray.run/blog/mastering-poms

Here is what it looks like when `.css` file is not loaded.

[image]

While I work to figure out why Google is failing to load the CSS, I would like to provide minimal CSS that's used before the `.css` file is loaded, e.g.

```
body { background: #040404; color: #e5e7eb; }

a { margin: 10px; display: inline-block; color: #2E8EFB; }
```

I can inline this CSS in HTML. However, it then conflicts with the CSS once the actual CSS is loaded. Is there a technique to erase the old CSS once the new CSS has been loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your temporary styles in a cascade layer, and use `revert-layer` to remove them, that way you will safely replace all your temporary styles without risking inadvertently removing other styles. So in the style element:

```css
<style>
  @layer temporary {
    body { background: #040404; color: #e5e7eb; }
    a { margin: 10px; display: inline-block; color: #2E8EFB; }
  }
</style>
```

In the linked style sheet, placed after the `<style>` element:

```css
@layer temporary {
  body, a { all: revert-layer; }
}
```

```html
<style>
  @layer temporary {
    body { background: #040404; color: #e5e7eb; }
    a { margin: 10px; display: inline-block; color: #2E8EFB; }
  }
</style>
<style>
  /* Not a temporary style - This should not be reverted by 
   * the linked style sheet 
   */
  body { background:green }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css, 
  /* Data-url for demonstration purposes. Would actually be
   * in an external file
   */
  @layer temporary {
    body, a { all: revert-layer; }
  }
">
Hello World
```

Comment: Woah, this exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your temporary styles in a `<style>` tag—that will make it easier to remove (though if you really want to use inline `style` attributes, you can remove those styles by querying for the elements and setting `style = ""`. E.g., `document.querySelector('body').style = ""`).

To perform those removals after your intended CSS has been loaded, try putting an `onload` event listener directly on the `<link>` tag. I just tried this out locally, and it worked fine.

```
<head>
  <!-- -->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="--your-intended-css--"
    onload="
      // if using style tag, simply remove it from DOM
      document.getElementById('temp-styles').remove();

      // if using inline styles, set each element's style to ''
      document.querySelector('body').style = '';
    "
  >
  
  <style id="temp-styles">
    body {
      background-color: red!important;
      font-size: 20rem!important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: blue!important;">
  <!-- -->
```